# Why isn't my while loop working through scp when reiterating through a list

Tags: bash, macos, scp

Hi I am trying to transfer a list of files from the server to my computer using a while loop, but it keeps giving me the error that there is no file or directory. I can't understand why.

So I have this file list_numbers.txt with over 500 lines

```
list_numbers.txt
1234
345
2135
2132
...
```

And I want to re-iterate through this list to transfer files from server to my computer with the corresponding foldername to my computer but replacing assembly_graph.txt with $line_for_assembly.txt

```
while read line; do scp -r user@server.com:/home/Documents/$line_assembly/assembly_graph.txt /Users/Documents/$line_for_assembly.txt; done < list_numbers.txt
```

So basically I want it to do the below code, but instead of me having to manually type it, it would re-iterate through the list.

```
scp -r user@server.com:/home/Documents/1234_assembly/assembly_graph.txt /Users/Documents/1234_for_assembly.txt

scp -r user@server.com:/home/Documents/345_assembly/assembly_graph.txt /Users/Documents/345_for_assembly.txt

scp -r user@server.com:/home/Documents/2135_assembly/assembly_graph.txt /Users/Documents/2135_for_assembly.txt

scp -r user@server.com:/home/Documents/2132_assembly/assembly_graph.txt /Users/Documents/2132_for_assembly.txt
```

But I get this error:

```
scp: /home/Documents//assembly_graph.txt: No such file or directory
```

So it is not picking up the $line_assembly, even when I do ${line}_assembly. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you notice, `$line_assembly` is not being processed.    There should be some directory between those two forward slash `//` between *Documents* and *assembly_graph.txt*.

Comment: Please add what input file looks like and the directory structure of target file system. Also an explination of exactly what youre trying to do.  It looks like youre trying to take input from a file and use those lines in scp as a directory path. Does that sound right.

Comment: Hi goose goose, I updated the question.

Comment: When you do it manually does it work ?

Comment: Yes. It works manually

Comment: Try quoting the variable like user@server.com:/home/Documents/"$line"_assembly/assembly_graph.txt /Users/Documents/"$line"_for_assembly.txt; done < list_numbers.txt

Comment: Thanks goose! The quotes worked, but I think there's something wrong with the list of files I'm giving it, its picking up the numbers in the list_numbers.txt but still saying there is not filename blah blah. So I'll look into that. But at least its reading it now. Thank you!

Comment: The next thing is because the syntax is scp host then destination the part you have for host is /Users/Documents/$line_for_assembly.txt has to exist furthermore and most importantly on the destination be sure to use the user@ syntax and the directory /Users/Documents exists

Comment: scp [OPTION] [user@]SRC_HOST:]file1 [user@]DEST_HOST:]file2

Comment: Ohhhh I see. I'll give that a go. Thanks goose goose!

Comment: Did you see the "this has already been answered" part. Up top. Thats the problem solver

Comment: I did but it wasn't doing it for me. Then GMc gave the idea that there could be characters in my list! Its working now. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you do not have a variable named line_assembly.

Perhaps you mean to the following:

```sh
while read line
 do
  line=`echo $line | tr -d '\r\n'`
   scp -r user@server.com:/home/Documents/${line}_assembly/assembly_graph.txt /Users/Documents/${line}_for_assembly.txt
done < list_numbers.txt
```

this will expand as the value of line followed by the text "_assembly".

For example if "line" has the value "component" you will get

.../Documents/component_assembly/...

EDIT: OP had spurious characters in his/her input file (probably \r characters from windows). I've edited the answer accordingly to accommodate OP's specific issue.

Comment: Hi GMc, I tried this, but its giving me this error now ```_assembly/assembly_graph.txt: No such file or directory```

Comment: I guess I can not see any of your directories, so I can only ask does that file exist on the remote (or local) system?

Also, I noticed in my answer I did not properly "escape" the destination path which will have the exact same problem, so I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also, you might need to make sure your input file does not have any spurious characters.

You might try adding ```line=`echo $line | tr -d '\r\n'` ``` just before the scp

Comment: OMG. It worked. It was the line=`echo $line | tr -d '\r\n'` that did the trick. I guess there were extra characters I didn't see. Its been doing my head in! Thank you so much GMc!!!

Comment: You are most welcome and thanks for accepting my answer (most do not - even those that log a comment that said it solved their problem). BTW. For future reference, you can see the "detailed contents of a file with ```hexdump -C list_numbers.txt``` Try it on your file. Normally, Linux text files end their line with a single linefeed character which will show as 0A in hexdump. Windows text files use two characters which will show as 0D 0A in hexdump.

Comment: You saved me hours of having to manually type scp for each file, so really - thank you! Ah, thats a handy one-liner file check! I think because I saved it as a text file from an xlsx file so it must have picked up extra characters. Good to know!